# Jquery: How to unwrap all span tags for a string while keeping the text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wondered how to unwrap all span tags for a string while keeping all the text.

My attempt:

```
<script>
mystr="<span id=1>firstword</span><span id=2>secondword</span>";
var element = $(mystr);//convert string to JQuery element
var result= element.find("span").contents().unwrap(); 
alert(result);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use text() of jquery.
ir replaces your  tags

jsfiddle.net/7dew9zqs/

Answer (score 2):

Your spans are not nested inside any other elements. Check the results of the following:

```js
mystr="<div><span id=1>firstword</span><span id=2>secondword</span></div>";
var element = $(mystr);//convert string to JQuery element
var result= element.find("span").contents().unwrap(); 
alert(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that the `.find()` function will look into descendants of your element. You are however looking at top level elements.

In order to grab each of the text nodes separately you can do the following to loop through each of the spans in your string and alert the text.

```
element.each(function(i, ele){
   alert($(ele).text())
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `unwrap()` is correct, but you need `element`'s content. So try this:

```js
var mystr = "<span>firstword</span><span>secondword</span>";
var element = $('<div></div>').html(mystr);
alert(element.html());
element.find("span").contents().unwrap(); 
alert(element.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```